# Switch back to main text after writing a comment in Word 2010/2013

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2013

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> shortcut allows me to quickly switch off the main text and start a comment.

Is there any shortcut, that would allow me to switch back to main text *after* editing that comment?

I'm working on a small screen and in Word 2013 comments line / margin / window takes a large part of screen. Thus, when I'm switching to editing comment, main text partially shifts off the left edge of screen. After comment is finished I need to not only click on main text to go back editing it, but I also must click a lot on scrollbars to bring viewport back to original state.

I was wondering, if there is any automation on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd> takes me back to the text. If it doesn't work for you, please give more details as to what you have enabled in your copy of Word so that it can be replicated.

Comment: Oh, God! It is that obvious? :>